# IE7 rendering performance

Tags: ajax, performance, internet-explorer-7

I have a JSF application that is updating sections of itself dynamically via AJAX.

It runs ridiculously slow in IE7, but later versions of IE are fine, along with Firefox and Chrome.

I suspect it is an issue with client-side rendering performance - it's a pretty big chunk of HTML that is being updated dynamically, and there's not much JS code besides updating the DOM with the response (analogous to `$(element).html(response)` in jQuery).

Can this be tracked down to specific elements or not?  For example, are there specific elements or CSS styles to focus on?  Where else should I be looking?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick work around is to use chromeframe.

It renders the page use chrome engine and you can put the frame in IE6,7 and 8

http://code.google.com/chrome/chromeframe/

Answer (score 0):

Dynatrace AJAX edition should be able to help you track down the issues - http://ajax.dynatrace.com/ajax/en/

Presume you're using jQuery are you using an up-to-date version?